# Nodejs mysql2 not throwing connection or query error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to capture connection error on nodejs while using mysql or mysql2 node module.
My code is

```
    console.log("Connecting to database")
    try{
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
            user     : process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database : process.env.DB_NAME
        });
        connection.connect();
        console.log("Connected")
    }
    catch(exce)
    {
        console.log(exce)
    }
```

The mysql server is not running and all details are wrong here. I am expecting this code to throw a connection error but this does not happen. Instead, I am receiving the following console output.

```
Connecting to database
Connected
```

I don`t know why there is no connection error thrown by mysql module.

Comment: Try this `connection.connect(function(err) { if (err) throw err; console.log("Connected");`

Comment: Try Promise-based version of `connect` with `await`

Comment: @Anatoly Thanks for your comment bro. This solution worked for me. I had to ``` var mysql = require("mysql2/promise")    ``` and put await before connection.create

Answer (score 0):

The following solution suggested by @Anatoly worked for me.

````
var mysql=require("mysql2/promise")
 var connected=true
    console.log("Connecting to database")
    try{
        var connection =await mysql.createConnection({
            host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
            user     : process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database : process.env.DB_NAME
        });
        // connection.connect();
        console.log("Connected")
    }
    catch(exce)
    {
        console.log(exce)
        connected=false
    }
```
````